# Cypress: How to display text value of a td element in the log?

Tags: cypress

i want given td value and display on the log without undrestude text value to cypress.(dynamic)

i wriiten the below code but it can't return text value.

cy.log((cy.get("tr td:nth-child(5)")))

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tls9F.png)

tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`cy.get('tr td:nth-child(5)')` yields a `Chainable<JQueryElement>` type object, and not the text of the element yielded. In order to properly log or manipulate that text value, you'll have to chain off of the `cy.get()` command.

```js
cy.get('tr td:nth-child(5)').then(($el) => {
  cy.log($el.text()); // use the JQuery `.text()` command
});
// or
cy.get('tr td:nth-child(5)')
  .invoke('text') // invoke the text attribute
  .then((text) => {
    cy.log(text);
  });
```